# Grub2 splash screen appears for 30 seconds despite efforts to reduce it

Tags: grub2

I want to remove or greatly reduce the time for which the GRUB screen appears. I have used GRUB customizer and gedit. All the values are what they need to be, yet the screen remains for 30 seconds. Using Ubuntu 18.04.

What could be the problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: No one can verify that "all the values are what they need to be" based on the information you have provided. [edit] your question and include the complete text of /etc/default/grub.

Comment: @stevej you mean splash screen or the grub menu options screen??

Comment: @OrganicMarble That won't help if it is UEFI+LVM or btrfs.

Comment: I don't understand why no one has looked at the manual for `grub-mkconfig` or `update-grub` where they advocate only running the command during distribution upgrade or when discovering new kernels to generate new entries. It is a dangerous command that can reconfigure the grub and cause boot failure. Advocating the change to /etc/default/grub requires running `update-grub` for it to be effective, while editing the timeout values in grub.cfg is quick, simple and does not actually change the main structure of the grub.cfg itself. If you only change these timeout values who can mess anything up!

Comment: @Pilot6 We don't know what it is based on the limited info provided.

Comment: The 30 sec no matter what is in `/etc/default/grub` is clear enough.

Comment: I do have UEFI+LVM so appears I will just have to live with it unless there is a way around it. Thanks

Comment: There is a way around: get rid either of UEFI (switch to legacy), or LVM.

Comment: Hmmm, not the best suggestion if the user  in fact needs either LVM or UEFI. It's one of the things that will just need time, and devs eventually will figure out a better fix than hard-codded time